# How can I set primary key in particular text field?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

**My Code here**

```
db.execSQL("create table if not exists data(patient_name varchar,patient_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  ,patient_phone varchar,patient_mail varchar,patient_age,patient_gender varchar,patient_address varchar,patient_lvd varchar,patient_nvd varchar,patient_notes varchar)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

```
 String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " 
            + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
            + patient_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
            + patient_phone + " TEXT, " 
            + patient_name + " TEXT, " 
            + patient_phone + " TEXT  )";

 db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

You can follow **[SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)**